# asio::steady_timer does NOT work with completion handler "use_awaitable"

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, coroutine, asio

I am being confused the asio::timer coroutine with completion handler "use_awaitable" does not work if I modify the timer in another coroutine.

The "Leave foo" never reached:

```
Enter foo
Enter bar
Leave bar
The End
```

Below is code:

```cpp
static asio::awaitable<void> foo(asio::steady_timer& timer)
{
    cout << "Enter foo" << endl;
    timer.expires_from_now(asio::steady_timer::clock_type::duration::max());
    co_await timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
    cout << "Leave foo" << endl;
}

static asio::awaitable<void> bar(asio::steady_timer& timer)
{
    cout << "Enter bar" << endl;
    sleep(2); // wait a little for asio::io_service::run to be executed
    timer.expires_after(asio::chrono::seconds(1));
    cout << "Leave bar" << endl;
    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    asio::io_context ioService;
    asio::steady_timer timer(ioService);

    asio::co_spawn(ioService, foo(timer), asio::detached);
    asio::co_spawn(ioService, bar(timer), asio::detached);

    ioService.run();
    std::printf("The End\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Actually I just want to suspend a coroutine and resume it in another coroutine over asio/c++20 without any other threads.

Comment: "*I just want to suspend a coroutine and resume it in another coroutine*" Then you need to get one coroutine to know about the other one. The standard way to do that is for one coroutine to be the invoker of the other.

Comment: Hi @NicolBolas, thanks for your reply, but I am not quite sure I got your point. I have two socket servers in a same io context, one is suspending until the other receives a certain signal to resume it. This is my case. Does it mean it is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs state that `expires_after` cancels any pending async wait. Using `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING`:

[image]

You don't handle the exception. If you did, you would notice it happening:

```
static asio::awaitable<void> foo(asio::steady_timer& timer) try {
    std::cout << "Enter foo" << std::endl;
    timer.expires_from_now(asio::steady_timer::clock_type::duration::max());
    co_await timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
    std::cout << "Leave foo" << std::endl;
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << se.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Now the output is

```
Enter foo
Enter bar
Leave bar
Error: Operation canceled [system:125]
The End
```

Alternatively you might use error-codes:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
co_await timer.async_wait(redirect_error(asio::use_awaitable, ec));
std::cout << "Leave foo (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
```

Or even:

```
auto [ec] = co_await timer.async_wait(as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable));
std::cout << "Leave foo (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
```

Both printing ([Live](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/a8jE6PvEb)):

```
Enter foo
Enter bar
Leave bar
Leave foo (Operation canceled)
The End
```

### More Problems / Ideas

There's a problem with `sleep`-ing in a coro. It block the execution context, so no asynchronous work will be able to complete. That's certainly not what you want.

Besides, it looks a lot like you are trying to coordinate execution of two coroutines. If you want "signal-like" behaviour, then by all means, this can work as long as you correctly handle the error-codes as well.

If you just want to coordinate cancellation, use the `cancellation_slot` facility. In fact, there exists pretty powerful syntactic sugar for binding shared cancellation slots across `asio::awaitable<>` instances:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f93c9c96f0b12dd3)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

static void trace(char const* msg) {
    static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static auto const start = now();
    std::cout << std::setw(4) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " << msg << std::endl;
}

static asio::awaitable<void> async_simulate_work(auto delay) {
    co_await asio::steady_timer(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, delay)
        .async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
}

static asio::awaitable<void> foo() try {
    trace("Foo enter");
    for (;;) {
        trace("Foo working...");
        co_await async_simulate_work(100ms);
    }
    trace("Foo leave");
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    trace("Foo cancel");
}

static asio::awaitable<void> bar() {
    trace("Bar enter");
    co_await async_simulate_work(260ms);
    trace("Bar leave");
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context   ioService;
    asio::steady_timer timer(ioService);

    asio::co_spawn(ioService, foo() || bar(), asio::detached);

    ioService.run();
    trace("The End");
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
    g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
   0ms Foo enter
   0ms Foo working...
   0ms Bar enter
 100ms Foo working...
 200ms Foo working...
 260ms Bar leave
 260ms Foo cancel
 260ms The End
```