# Use error codes with C++20 Coroutines i.e. awaitables with Boost ASIO

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-asio

Lets say for example I have a `boost::asio::steady_timer timer` that I want to async wait on with `boost::asio::steady_timer::async_wait`. In the old way I get errors as code parameter in my completion handler i.e. my lambda like

```
timer.async_wait([](const auto &boost_error) {
            //check boost_error
        });
```

With Co routines I am able to `co_await` when using `boost::asio::use_awaitable` as

```
co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::use_awaitable);
```

However the error handling has changed: In order to catch errors, like an `cancel`ed timer, I have to wrap my co_await in a try/catch block.

Can I get boost to let me await on the async operation but giving me the error as a code, like

```
 std::variant<void, error_code> = co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::use_awaitable);
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close: `as_tuple(use_awaitable)` works almost exactly like that:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/KEGxPjYve)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

asio::awaitable<void> timer(auto duration) {
    auto [ec] = co_await asio::steady_timer{co_await asio::this_coro::executor, duration}.async_wait(
        as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable));
    std::cout << "Wait for " << (duration / 1.s) << "s: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    asio::co_spawn(ioc, timer(3s) || timer(1500ms), asio::detached);

    ioc.run();
}
```

Prints:

```
Wait for 1.5s: Success
Wait for 3s: Operation canceled
```

Alternative adaptors: `asio::redirect_error` and `asio::as_single`

Comment: As always: Many thanks, you seem to be always exactly one step ahead :-). 
Nitpick: Could you give examples with the redirect error? Now I know what to try, but I you want to write the perfect answer, you know ;-).

Comment: I just made one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76922642/85371

Comment: I see thank you. To my defense: In hind sight, it's always logical with boost, and elegant with all that meta programming, but with just lofty concepts, >7 overloads + meta programming I would say its sometimes hard to understand the implications out from the documentation. Until next time, I hope the day will come where I answer a question of yours :-)

Comment: I see thank you. To my defense: In hind sight, it's always logical with boost, and elegant with all that meta programming, but with just lofty concepts, >7 overloads + meta programming I would say its sometimes hard to understand the implications out from the documentation. Until next time, I hope the day will come where I answer a question of yours :-)

Comment: No need to defend :) As you note, I'm only just a step ahead on the same hill!